# What's the difference between r'string' and normal 'string' in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string

What's the difference between an r string (`r'foobar'`) and a normal string (`'foobar'`) in Python? Is r'string' a regex string?

I've tried the following and there aren't any effects on my regex matches:

```
>>> import re
>>> n = 3
>>> rgx = '(?=('+'\S'*n+'))'
>>> x = 'foobar'
>>> re.findall(rgx,x)
['foo', 'oob', 'oba', 'bar']
>>>
>>> rgx2 = r'(?=('+'\S'*n+'))'
>>> re.findall(rgx2,x)
['foo', 'oob', 'oba', 'bar']
>>>
>>> rgx3 = r'(?=(\S\S\S))'
>>> re.findall(rgx3,x)
['foo', 'oob', 'oba', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`r` doesn't signify a "regex string"; it means "raw string". As per [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

> String literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter `'r'` or `'R'`; such strings are called *raw strings* and use different rules for interpreting backslash escape sequences.

They are commonly *used* (and [recommended](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)) for regular expressions because regex and non-raw strings *both* use backslashes as an escape character. For example, to match a literal backslash with a regex in a normal string would be `'\\\\'`; using a raw string, it's just `'\\'`.

Comment: OP: also read [Raw String Notation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#raw-string-notation)

Answer (score 4):

The difference would become apparent in cases when you have backslash escapes:

```
>>> s="foobar"
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('(o)\1', '', s)     # Using the backreference has no effect here as it's interpreted as a literal escaped 1
'foobar'
>>> re.sub(r'(o)\1', '', s)    # Using the backreference works!
'fbar'
>>> re.sub('(o)\\1', '', s)    # You need to escape the backslash here
'fbar'
```

Quoting from [String literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#Raw_strings):

> A few languages provide a method of specifying that a literal is to be
> processed without any language-specific interpretation. This avoids
> the need for escaping, and yields more legible strings.

You might also want to refer to [Lexical Analysis](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).