# finding all instances of !!/ and replacing them with a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string in Python with !!/ in it and I am trying to substitute instances of !!/ with a string.

WHAT I AM TRYING:
I am using re.sub to find and replace, but my search string is made of all weird special characters so I am having trouble writing a regex that finds what I want to find.

MY CODE SO FAR:

```
re.sub('\/\s!\s!', new_text, raw_text)
```

My python program should find and replace all instances of !!/ inside raw_text with the new_text.  How can I do this Find/Replace in python with regex?

Comment: It would help if you posted the search string.

Comment: It should be `re.sub('!!\/', new_text, raw_text)`

Comment: why `\s!` ? `!!\/` will find exactly `!!/`

Comment: Can you add some example strings with the data to be replaced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex should be `!!\/`

```
raw_text = "!!/ world"
new_text = "Hello"

s = re.sub('!!\/', new_text, raw_text)
print (s)

Hello world
```

Comment: There is no need to backslash-escape the slash, either.

Comment: that one did it, ! I think I tried every combination of escaping and \s-ing except that one! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex to replace a fixed string. Use the `str.replace` method instead for better clarity and efficiency:

```
raw_text = raw_text.replace('!!/', new_text)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `!!/` string is a literal, you don't need regex.

```
raw_text = raw_text.replace('!!/', new_text)
```

If you want to permit arbitrary runs of whitespace between the characters, add `*` quantifiers:

```
raw_text = re_sub(r'!\s*!\s*/', new_text, raw_text)
```

Your regex would match `'/ ! !'` which has the characters in a different order (slash before exclams) and non-optional spaces between the characters.

The `*` quantifier means "zero or more of the previous expression"; there is also `?` for "zero or one" and `+` for "one or more".

I have assumed the old value of `raw_text` should be replaced so the variable ends up with an updated value.

Comment: I did get the answer, but I am curious what the re.sub(r does rather than just re.sub(

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429505/whats-the-difference-between-rstring-and-normal-string-in-python